# Построение гистограммы специального вида

Tags: python, matplotlib, big-data, гистограммы

Надо построить гистограмму специального вида. Знаю, что для этого есть функция `hist`, но не знаю точно, как её применить в данном случае.

Данные представлены в следующем виде в файле:

```
3 0 0.25 0.35 0.45 
5 0.45 0.65
4 0.65 0.68 0.69 0.70
...
```

Первый столбец показывает частоту попадания значения в набор интервалов. Набор интервалов представлен столбцами `2-...` (т.е. может быть произвольное количество). Так, первая строка означает "в набор интервалов `{[0; 0.25], [0.35; 0.45)}` попадает 3 значения". Все данные представлены правильно, т.е. первая точка первого интервала в наборе интервалов является последней точкой в последнем интервале предыдущего набора интервалов, интервалы идут последовательно и т.д.. Однако в наборе интервалов интервалы, хоть и расположены правильно друг относительно друга, являются разрывными (т.е. первая точка интервала != последней точке предыдущего).

Включения для наборов интервалов: `[_), [_), ..., [_), [_]`. Включения для интервалов внутри набора интервалов `[_], [_], ..., [_], [_)`, если набор интервалов не последний. А если набор интервалов последний, то включения интервалов в нём `[_], ..., [_]`.

Как отобразить это на гистограмме так, чтобы по `x` были наборы интервалов, а по `y` - частоты?

Comment: Раз неизвестно распределение между подынтервалами, значит, придётся для первого набора рисовать два столбика равной высоты 3, а между ними пустоту, так?

Comment: @MBo надо чтобы было понятно, что это один набор интервалов. Не знаю, может разными цветами сделать 2 столбика одинаковой высоты, но лучше сделать один стобик с подписью внизу `{[0; 0.25], [0.35; 0.45)}` и продолжать дальше `x` начиная с `0.45`

Comment: @MBo ширина стобиков не важна, они могут не соответствовать сумме длин интервалов, главное - чтобы было ясно что в таком-то наборе интервалов такая-то частота

Comment: Может быть,  столбики одним цветом, промежутки между столбиками одного набора - таким же бледным цветом. Собственно, не очень ясно - имеет ли смысл презентация этих пустот юзеру.

Comment: @MBo не знаю, но точно не стоит: 1) брать первую точку первого интервала и последнюю последнего в наборе интервалов, вводя пользователя в заблеждение, что разрывов нет ; 2) сделать гистограмму для подинтервалов, никак не показывая что подинтервалы принадлежат одному набору. Было бы круто, если бы вы показали несколько возможных вариантов

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так. Показал бы бледно или полупрозрачной заливкой -  столбики по интервалам интервалов, а ярко, как бы на фоне первых - столбики по интервалам. Тогда бы вся реальная информация, которая у вас есть, стала-бы доступна пользователю - и об объединенности интервалов и о наличии интервалов с нулевым попаданием точек.